# What does "a good player" mean in the movie Training day?

Tags: dialogue, training-day

In the movie *Training day*, during Jake and Alonzo's initial meeting with Roger the following dialogue occurs:

> ROGER: Where you grew up?
>
> JAKE: North Hollywood.
>
> ROGER: Strong safety, North Hollywood High.

Seeing Alonzo's confusion, Roger further elaborates --

> ROGER: I follow all the good players.

*What does Roger mean by "players"?*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Jake was a "player" in that school playing the position of Strong safety.

[Strong Safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_(gridiron_football_position)) is a position in American football and [North Hollywood High](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Hollywood_High_School) is a public high school.

> Safety, historically known as a safetyman, is a position in American and Canadian football played by a member of the defense. The safeties are defensive backs who line up from ten to fifteen yards from the line of scrimmage. There are two variations of the position in a typical American formation: the free safety (FS) and the strong safety (SS).